# Not able to add a new certificate for Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode5.1

I am configuring a new computer for iOS development. For some reason the automatic Xcode 5.1.1 setup machine for development fails so I am doing it manually. I have created a certificate on my local machine and I know needs to upload it to Developer portal but the option to create a new development certificate is not active as shown in the image below:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have one?

Comment: That looks like you already have one for development.  I'm guessing you lost the private key and are trying to start over?  You can probably just revoke your existing certificate and generate a new one.